# Change the key for signing in Android

Tags: android

The Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) states:

> You must use the same key to sign future versions of your application. If you republish your app with a new key, Google Play will consider it a new app.

There is also a link to [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html) that again claims that you can publish an app with the same package name and a different key for the signature although the user will have to eventually uninstall the version signed with the old key.

However when I try to publish an application that I signed with a key that is not the same that was used the first time the application was published I get an error:

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate

I have also found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642293/change-signing-key-keep-packagename) that states that you can't.

So the question is: is it possible and if not why the Android docs says something different?

Comment: ya right we can't upload the apk with different sign keystore. You should have the same keystore for the same package for singing.

Comment: no where in the android docs or that blog post does it say you can do that, I am not sure what you are reading

Comment: If we changing the package name and we can sign with same keystore then it behave like the different app.

Comment: @tyczy in the linked page: "If you republish your app with a new key, Google Play will consider it a new app.". From this statement I would think that it is possible to republish an application with the same package and a different key. If it meant with a different package it would be silly to specify that Google Play will consider it a different app: it would have a different author and a different package so clearly it would be a different application. I keep thinking that the doc is misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can use a different certificate. You just cannot upload it to Google Play if the certificate is different to a previously uploaded one.

Nothing stops you installing the apk manually though after uninstalling the one with a different signature..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sign with a different key. They won't let you upload it. I don't see where in this blog entry it says you can upload with a different certificate.  It seems to be listed under "Things that cannot change."

> > Just as important as the manifest package name is the certificate that application is signed with. The signing certificate represents the author of the application. If you change the certificate an application is signed with, it is now a different application because it comes from a different author. This different application can’t be uploaded to Market as an update to the original application, nor can it be installed onto a device as an update.

Comment: right but when the blog explains what happens if you change the signature key it says that the user will have to uninstall the application. It does not say that you cannot upload it.