# How to change the signature for apk on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have deployed a beta application to google play store. But now I want to redeploy a new version of my apk file. But the playstore always tolds me that I have to use the upload signature to do an upload.
I used a keystore and added also the uploadsignature to it with this

```
keytool.exe -importcert -file upload_cert.der -keystore <keystorefile>
```

What can be the problem. Is there a way to remove completely the beta apk and to add a completely new one without recreating a new app?

Comment: I find it unclear why you aren't signing the new APK with the same keystore as the previous APK.

Comment: because for error I have used last time a wrong keystore that i don't have anymore :-(

Comment: Ok, well, if you're using Google Play's app signing feature, see the last item [on this help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en). If you're signing the app yourself you will break the update functionality. That is, users with a previous version of the app will most likely have to uninstall it before they can install the new one that you have signed with a different keystore. The takeaway here is, if you're managing the keystore yourself, **make sure you never lose it**. Keep backups somewhere safe.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for your help. But sorry I am a little bit confused. This is one of my first mobile apps. I have seen that I use the Google Play App Signing. This means that i can upload a not signed apk file and Google signs it for me? Or I have to sign it with my Keystore file? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change signing key, keep packagename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642293/change-signing-key-keep-packagename)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look after your signing keys. Luckily you use [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en). When you do this, you must sign your APK with a key called an "upload key" then Google Play will sign it for you with the production key.

It sounds like you have lost your upload key. Google Play support can fix this for you if you contact them. You need to follow the steps in [this help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756#reset)

Comment: one question where I get the upload_certificate.pem or I have to create it?

Comment: Have you read the link I sent? It says, in step 1 "generate private new private key and upload certificate" "To generate and register a new upload key, follow the instructions in the Android Studio Help Center" https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key Please make some effort to read and understand items for yourself.