# How can I migrate a released app to a new firebase project?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Cause: Noob me released an app a few years ago without realising that I had set a far away location for my Firestore bucket. I can't change the location of the Firestore bucket once set, as warned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#default-cloud-location)

Requirement: I need to change the Firebase project my released app uses.

Problem:

1. I can't change the package name or signing key for the app I have already released on Play Store - as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642293/change-signing-key-keep-packagename), i.e. I am stuck with my package-SHA pair unless I want to put a new listing on Play store
2. The firebase project my app uses is decided at build time via the google-services.json file.
3. I can't have the same package-SHA pair registered to multiple firebase projects at a time - as per [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008?authuser=0).

All this means that I can only have one release build working at a time - either the one that points to the old project or one that points to the new project. And since this is a mobile app, the adoption of any new release by users takes time.

What could be an approach to migrate my users without my app's earlier version just dropping dead when I switch the SHA keys? It will drop dead because Firebase Auth needs the SHA keys to be registered.